# Can I grab the project output app.config file in the XML file Changes area of InstallShield 2012?

Tags: app-config, installshield, installshield-2012

I need to change a couple paths from the debug/testing App.config files to their final home on the end user's machine.  I see the XML File Changes option when editing the Installer project through Visual studio, and the help indicates I should Import the xml file to be changed.

BUT...

Is there any way to import the  output of the project for the XML file?  If I browse directly to the file itself I have to use the Debug or Release config file, which seems like it would be annoying.  Otherwise I could use the base App.config but if any transformations are applied when building they'd be lost.

So am I stuck with just browsing to a file, or can I grab the "Project Output" somehow like I can for the .exe file?

Answer (score 1):

XML File Changes is pretty weak tea. 
To do what you are looking for your going to have to create a custom action that loads the .config file and updates it outside of InstallShield.

If you are using 2012 C# Wizard project type an option should be to create a .rul that catches the OnEnd() event in After Move Data. From the .rul call into a dll via UseDLL and invoke a method that accepts the target path to the config and the value to update the value to.

The following is code I'm testing so... 
Using a C# Wizard project type I added the following InstallScript rule to call into a C# dll:

```
function OnEnd()
string basePath;
BOOL bResult;
string dllPath;
OBJECT oAppConfig;
begin

dllPath = TARGETDIR ^ APPCONFIG_DLL;
try
    set oAppConfig = DotNetCoCreateObject(dllPath, "AppConfig.ConfigMgr", "");
catch
    MessageBox("Error Loading" + dllPath + ": "  + Err.Description, INFORMATION); 
    abort;
endcatch;

try
    basePath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MyCompany\\Config Test\\";
    bResult = oAppConfig.ConfigureSettings(basePath + "appsettings.xml", basePath + "app.config", "someAppSection");
catch
    MessageBox("Error calling ConfigureSettings " + dllPath + " " + Err.Number + " " + Err.Description, INFORMATION);
endcatch;

end;
```

C# test code:
        public bool ConfigureSettings(string configFilePath, string targetAppConfigPath, string targetAppName)
        {
            bool completed = true;

```
        try
        {
            XmlDocument configFileDoc = new XmlDocument();
            configFileDoc.Load(configFilePath);

            string installerTargetFileDoc = targetAppConfigPath; // InstallShield's build process for Visual Studio solutions does not rename the app.config file - Awesome!
            System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(installerTargetFileDoc);
            if (fi.Exists == false) installerTargetFileDoc = "app.config";
            XmlDocument targetAppConfigDoc = new XmlDocument();
            targetAppConfigDoc.Load(installerTargetFileDoc);

            // ensure all required keys exist in the target .config file
            AddRequiredKeys(configFileDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/" + targetAppName + "/requiredKeys"), ref targetAppConfigDoc);

            // loop through each key in the common section of the configuration file
            AddKeyValues(configFileDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/common/appSettings"), ref targetAppConfigDoc);

            // loop through each key in the app specific section of the configuration file - it will override the standard configuration
            AddKeyValues(configFileDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/" + targetAppName + "/appSettings"), ref targetAppConfigDoc);

            // save it off
            targetAppConfigDoc.Save(targetAppConfigPath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            completed = false;
            throw ex;
        }
        return completed;
    }
    private void AddKeyValues(XmlNode configAppNodeSet, ref XmlDocument targetAppConfigDoc)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode configNode in configAppNodeSet.SelectNodes("add"))
        {
            XmlNode targetNode = targetAppConfigDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/appSettings/add[@key='" + configNode.Attributes["key"].Value + "']");
            if (targetNode != null)
            {
                targetNode.Attributes["value"].Value = configNode.Attributes["value"].Value;
            }
        }
    }
    private void AddRequiredKeys(XmlNode targetAppNodeSet, ref XmlDocument targetAppConfigDoc)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode targetNode in targetAppNodeSet.SelectNodes("key"))
        {
            // add the key if it doesn't already exist
            XmlNode appNode = targetAppConfigDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/appSettings/add[@key='" + targetNode.Attributes["value"].Value + "']");
            if (appNode == null)
            {
                appNode = targetAppConfigDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/appSettings");
                XmlNode newAddNode = targetAppConfigDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "add", null);
                XmlAttribute newAddNodeKey = targetAppConfigDoc.CreateAttribute("key");
                newAddNodeKey.Value = targetNode.Attributes["value"].Value;
                XmlAttribute newAddNodeValue = targetAppConfigDoc.CreateAttribute("value");
                newAddNodeValue.Value = "NotSet";
                newAddNode.Attributes.Append(newAddNodeKey);
                newAddNode.Attributes.Append(newAddNodeValue);
                appNode.AppendChild(newAddNode);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

While it seems like it should work, Installshield is unable to grok project output correctly (dependencies are missed often, merge modules are duplicated even when they dont apply), or give you a way to deal with individual files in project output.

I have no less than 5 bugs open with them about problems using project output and their workaround is always "Add the files manually".

If you are just getting started with install shield, I suggest you try another alternative. If you have to use it, either complain about this not working to their support team and use the suggested workaround until they get it together.

This may not be the "answer" to your question, but hopefully helps your sanity when dealing with the broken feature set in this product.

Comment: I find it amazing this integration is so broken considering its now the packaging project of choice in VS.

Answer (score 0):

You can import any file you want (by browsing), and make changes to it in any run-time location you like. I suggest just putting the minimal amount you need to make your changes; after all it's the XML File *Changes* view. That way most updates to the file won't cause or require any changes to your XML File Changes settings, no matter how it's included.

Comment: But I don't want to import a specific file, I want to import the project output.  That way I can get the correct base xml file for debug or release depending on which build configuration I'm using for Visual Studio.